# asp.net menu xml -xpath not found

Tags: asp.net, xml, web

I have asp.net menu that uses xml datasource here's the html code:

```
                <DataBindings>
                    <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="Menu" NavigateUrlField="Nav" TextField="Text" ToolTipField="Text" />
                </DataBindings>

            </asp:Menu>


             <asp:XmlDataSource XPath="/Menus/Menu" ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/data.xml" >
        </asp:XmlDataSource>
```

The xml is at:
http://www.nlprogramming.net/data.xml

The error is that the Nav property not found for navigateurlfield 
Can u help me?
Thanks